# Q regarding finding sum of first 2002 terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Q : A sequence of integers $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}$ satisfies $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}$ $-a_{n}$ for $n \geq 1$. Suppose the sum of first 999 terms is 1003 and the sum of the first 1003 terms is - 999. Find the sum of the first 2002 terms.

My questions regarding this problem are:

1. What will be the 1st term ?

Since they say n ≥1. So , do we say 1st term of the sequence has n = 2.

$a_{2+2} = a_{2+1} - a_2$

2. It will be great if u could please share different-different ways u can solve it. Also , a very important point is that : What are you thinking at every step while solving this Q. This really helps me a lot because then I can also know what is the way you’re trying to find the solution. Like if it’s a method you’re using , did you already know about it ? Or you’re thinking of ways to find the solution i.e how are u thinking to find ways to solve ?

3)What I have tried:

- Sum of 1000th - 1003th term:

1003 - ( -999) = 2002.

- What we need to find is the sum of next 999terms. I’m not able to solve further than that.

4. Also , please share if you what are the other method that we can use ?

Thank you.

Comment: @dxiv It’s a Q of my textbook. Chapter is progression & series. Sequences means like a1,a2,a3. The terms. & recurrences means repetition

Comment: You could start with $\,a_{n+_2}+a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-a_{n}+a_{n}-a_{n-1}=a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}\,$ then push that farther.

Comment: @dxiv I’m unable to render math Jax.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a technical problem that you'll need to fix on your side if you want to get much anything out of MSE. You'll really need mathjax around here.

Comment: @dxiv Now , it’s working.

Comment: @dxiv Why did you think of adding $a_{n+2}$ + $a_{n+1}$. What made u think to only add these 2 terms ?

Comment: As my Q states above , I really want to know how you’re thinking while solving this Q. It will be a big understanding for me that way to further solve Q’s.

Comment: Reason to start adding terms are that 1) the question is about a sum, and 2) the recurrence relation you have very much suggests [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#In_general). Of course, you wouldn't stop at adding just those two terms.

Comment: @dxiv K. Interesting.

Comment: @dxiv I have found a relation. I just did it.Adding first 6 terms of the sequence gives sum = 0.I can say this is telescoping right ?

Comment: @dxiv K. Thanks. From here , I can solve the Q further. Do u know some other way too?

Comment: If you solved it then it's perfectly OK, even encouraged, that you post a self-answer with the details. I'll +1 tomorrow, assuming it's the correct answer, of course.

Comment: @dxiv Pls check sir. I did add.

Comment: @S.M.T You should add the answer as a separate post, not within your question. This way you can also mark the question as answered.

Comment: @AndreasLenz K.

Comment: @S.M.T Looks good (+1).

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. Sir or ma’am ?

Answer (score 1):

M:1 = Telescoping

I can see we can’t do anything after this. So , I use telescoping method w/ the help of user dxiv.

$\begin{aligned} a_{n+2} &=a_{n+1}-a_{n} \\ \therefore \quad a_{n+3} &=a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} \\ &=a_{n+1}-a_{n}-a_{n+1} \\ &=-a_{n} \end{aligned}$ $$ \begin{array}{ll}a_{n+4} & =a_{n+3}-a_{n+2} \\ \therefore \quad a_{n+5} & =a_{n+4}-a_{n+3} \\ \therefore \quad a_{n+4} & +a_{n+5}=a_{n+4}-a_{n+2} \\ \therefore \quad a_{n+5} & =-a_{n+2} \\ \therefore \quad a_{n}+a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+a_{n+3}+a_{n+4}+a_{n+5} & \\ & =a_{n}+a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}-a_{n}+a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}-a_{n+2} \\ & = & a_{n+1}+a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}=0\end{array} $$
Let $S_{n}$ denotes the sum of first $n$ terms
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_{999} &=S_{6 \times 166+3}=S_{3} &(\because \text { every '6' consecutive }\\
S_{1003} &=S_{6 \times 167+1}=S_{1}^{\circ} &\text { terms has sum zero. }) \\
S_{2002} &=S_{6 \times 333+4}=S_{4} & \\
S_{2002} &=S_{4}=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4} \\
&=S_{3}-a_{1} \\
&=1003-(-999) \\
&=2002
\end{aligned} \quad\left(\because a_{4}=-a_{1} \text { since } a_{n+3}=-a_{n}\right)
$$